# msbuild: build as to a appxbundle (AppxBundle=Always not working)

Tags: msbuild, build-process, appx

I have a shared Windows8.1 project with a Phone and Desktop project in it. I defined different configurations to build x86/x64 for desktop and ARM for phone.

msbuild works fine without error, but there is no final *.appxbundle file on the output folder (or anywhere else) although i set the parameter **AppxBundle=Always**.

my command looks like this:

> msbuild myApp.sln /p:OutputPath=%OUTPATH%;Configuration=Phone;Platform=ARM;AppxBundle=Always;AppxBundlePlatforms=ARM
>   /t:Rebuild,Publish

The output is:

```
OUTPATH
├── ForBundle
│   └── AppxManifest.xml
├── AppxManifest.xml
├── App.WindowsPhone.build.appxrecipe
├── App.WindowsPhone_3.2.1_ARM.appx
├── App.WindowsPhone_3.2.1_scale-100.appx
├── App.WindowsPhone_3.2.1_scale-140.appx
├── App.WindowsPhone_3.2.1_scale-180.appx
├── resources.pri
└── SomeDependency.winmd
```

I tried to pack this folder with makeappx.exe bundle but this didn't work and I realized the folder looks a bit different to what is into a appxbundle.

Creating a appxbundle via VS GUI is no problem, but I would like to automate that step!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a hint comment in `Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets`:

> When building on the command line or in TFS (determined by looking at the $(BuildingInsideVisualStudio) property), if build is
>   invoked on an
>           app package-producing project, the package for the project will be produced as part of building the project without specifying
>   any additional
>           flags or targets. This is control by an MSBuild property named GenerateAppxPackageOnBuild which is set to true by default.
>
> If $(BuildingInsideVisualStudio) = false and $(GenerateAppxPackageOnBuild) = true, then build will also produce a
>   package.
>     
>       true

Comment: thanks for your answer. I used msbuild WindowsPhone.jsproj instead of the soultion and creating appxbundles with AppxBundle=Always now works

Comment: For reference, this useful file can be found at: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppxPackage.Targets`

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the file has moved for VS 2022, new location isL

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\AppxPackage