# How to use msbuild command line to create a bundle but exclude test projects

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have a C# solution with VS 2017, containing an app project and a test project. I can use the "create app package" wizard to create one single bundle for x86 and x64. However, I would like to automate this process, which means I need to use msbuild in command line to do the same work.

With the reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35309142/creating-appxbundle-using-msbuild-for-x86x64arm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34919428/msbuild-build-as-to-a-appxbundle-appxbundle-always-not-working), I got:

```
msbuild .\MyProject.sln /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64" /p:Configuration=Debug
```

But I will get errors for my test projects, like:

*MakeAppx : error : Error info: error 80080204: The package with file name "Tests.XXXX.Shared.Uwp_1.0.0.0_x86_Debug.appx" and package full name "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx_1.0.0.0_x86__xxxxxxxxxxx" is not valid in the bundle because it has a different package family name than other packages in the bundle. The expected package name is xxxx-Test.xxxxTestApp....*

My guess is that I should not use "Always" for AppxBundle, but I cannot find any document online mentioning how to set this value as "If Needed". I also tried to add "Never" in project properties for the test project, but the command line argument seems to overwrite that.

So my question is: **How to exclude a test project from the solution when creating a bundle using msbuild in the command line?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to exclude a test project from the solution when creating a bundle using msbuild in the command line?

To resolve this issue, you can build the project file directly when you create a bundle using MSBuild in the command line:

```
msbuild .\YourProjectFile.csproj /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64" /p:Configuration=Debug
```

Alternatively, you can open test project file and add the following properties at the end of the first `<PropertyGroup>` element to exclude the test project to be included:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <AppxBundle>Never</AppxBundle>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48236085/msbuild-does-not-build-solution-file-because-of-mismatching-package-name) and [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps#address-errors-that-appear-when-you-bundle-more-than-one-app-in-the-same-solution) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After I add the property, msbuild will be able to finish but it only generate a bundle for x64 without x86. How do I fix this? When I use the wizard it can generate the bundle with both platforms.

Comment: Also, does this command actually build x86 and x64 first, and bundle them? I found that if I clean both and then run the command above, I will get errors about "Could not find a recipe file for the referenced UWP application"

Comment: @laishiekai, It works fine on mt side, I can get the bundle file `App1_1.0.0.0_x86_x64_Debug.appxbundle`. Makre sure the parameter is `/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64"` Both have x86 and x64 and is your system x86? It seems the x86 OS could not generate the x64 bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I figured out my issue and posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51892208/uwp-with-desktop-bridge-package-build-automation-with-msbuild/53181888#53181888